# Mobx listen to a value changes with computed does not work

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am trying to listen to a value changes with `mobx` computed expression, but I don't see any changes when I push a new value to the observed expression.

```
class List {
  @observable values = [];

  constructor() {
    computed(() => this.values).observe(changes => {
      console.log(changes);
    })
  }


  add(item) {
    this.values.push(Math.random());
  }

}

const list = new List();
list.add();
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `computed` will only track data it actually accesses. The only data accessed in your computed is the `changes`, a pointer to an array. Pushing a new value to that array will not change the pointer.

Remember: computeds produce values, reactions & autoruns produce side effects.

Your computed never produces a new value, so never triggers the `observer`.

Comment: A new value === a new reference?

Answer (score 0):

[**computed**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html) is used when you want to derive a new value from other observables. You could use [**observe**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html) instead:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/valasexixa/edit?js,console))**

```
class List {
  @observable values = [];

  constructor() {
    observe(this.values, (change) => {
      if (change.added) {
        console.log(`${change.added} got added to values`);
      }
    });
  }

  add(item) {
    this.values.push(Math.random());
  }
}

const list = new List();

setInterval(() => {
  list.add();
}, 1000);
```